# autoconf automake LDADD syntax

Tags: autoconf, automake

autoconf (automake) won't accept

`packagename_LDADD = wx-config --libs`

and wants you to use `packagename_LDFLAGS` instead.

The problem is `LDFLAGS` is put in the wrong place on the command line for this parameter to work. Can `LDADD` be forced to take it?

Answer (score 3):

Automake doesn't know that `wx-config --libs` is a shell expression you wish to expand.

Usually what you want to do here is hoist detection and invocation of `wx-config` to an autoconf m4 macro (or use one provided by wx widgets) and use the *result* as an explicit variable reference in automake.  At that point automake will realize it is a list of libraries to add & simmer down.